# Show snackbar by AlarmManager in any activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, snackbar

Please navigate me with the following problem.
I have an AlarmManager that send a notification at specific time only if my app isnt on foreground. My goal is the show a snackbar in any current activity if user uses my app right now and insert to this snackbar message from notification

In short. 
If app isnt on foreground - send notification. if it is - show snackbar. How to show a snackbar current activity?

Comment: Have your `AlarmManager` trigger code that raises an event via an event bus (e.g., `LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus). Have your activities each subscribe to the bus when they are visible (e.g., `onStart()`) and unsubscribe when they are hidden (e.g., `onStop()`). When an activity receives the bus event, they show the `Snackbar`. If nothing responds to the bus event, the code that raised the event knows that no `Snackbar` was shown, and it raises the `Notification`.

Comment: See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot3 and https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/LocalBroadcastManager for examples of the above, though they do something else in the UI instead of showing a `Snackbar`.

Comment: @CommonsWare thx man. just implemented it [: The last question - how to use Snackbar if as a 1st param i need to set View of current activity?

Comment: Your activity that receives the event bus event should have access to a `View` to use.